# Not able to parse xml which is having html entities tag attributes in java parsers without changing xml file

Tags: java, xml

I have an xml tag like this

```
<tag displayname = "&Sigma;n, &Sigma;n2, &Sigma;n3"/>
```

I am using code like this to parse the xml

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder()
InputSource is = new InputSource(inputStream);
Document dom = db.parse(is);
```

but i am getting an exception as follows.

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The entity "Sigma" was referenced, but not declared.
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source) ~[DOMParser.class:na]
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source) ~[DocumentBuilderImpl.class:na]
```

Any one let me know how to solve this problem

Comment: But I need to solve using JAVA parsers without changing xml file.

Comment: Check out [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/), it is generally less restrictive on the content structure. It is primarily for HTML, but works with XML quite well, too.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56171601/flying-saucer-not-recognizing-html-entities/56176800#56176800